# One example about modification and indistinguishable

Tags: probability, analysis, stochastic-processes

Let $U$ be a r.v. which is uniformly distributed on the interval $[0,1]$. The probability space on which $U$ is defined is denoted by $(\Omega, F, P)$. Define two stochastic processes $\{X_t: t\in [0,1]\}$ and $\{Y_t: t\in [0,1]\}$ by $X_t(\omega)=0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$ and $Y_t(\omega)=1$ if $t=U(\omega)$ otherwise $Y_t(\omega)=0$.

Then
$$
P(X_t(\omega)\neq Y_t(\omega))=P(U(\omega)=t)=?
$$
Why this one is equal to zero?

Comment: Well this is a basic fact of measure theory that a uniform random variables puts 0 mass at any particular point as any continuous random variables. Or more formally it's simply the fact that $\lambda(\{x\}) =0 $ where $\lambda$ is Lebesgue's measure for any $x\in [0,1]$.

Comment: @TheBridge I know that the measure of a point is zero. But I am confused about the meaning of $P(U(\omega)=t)$. Here $t $ is fixed as a point? Does $U(\omega)=t$ mean this r.v. is always equal to a point?